# FileNotFoundException when I want to copy a file

Tags: android, copy

I've wrote method below to copy my backup file to external storage

```
public Boolean Backup() {
    try {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            File sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("");

            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            String dbPath = "//data//" + "com.example.sqlitetest"
                    + "//databases//" + "TestDB";

            // Backup file name
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String backupName = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"
                    + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
                    + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
                    + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                    + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                    + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            String backupPath = "//BackupFiles";

            File db = new File(data, dbPath);

            File backup = new File(sd + backupPath, backupName);

            if (!backup.exists())
                backup.mkdirs();

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(db).getChannel();
            FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(backup).getChannel();

            dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dest.close();

            return true;
        } else
            return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}
```

I've added permissions to write and read external storage. The destination folder is created (sd + backupPath) but files no and throws FileNotFoundException! How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String dbPath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator
                    + "databases" + File.separator + "TestDB";
```

And instead of using `//`, try `File.separator`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dbPath variable is already a full absolute path name, so can't be used in combination with a File object referring to your data directory, but only on its own.  And you got that full path name by making poor assumptions anyway.

What you should do is obtain a File representing the data directory as you are, and use it in combination with a String containing just a filename (within that) and not an absolute directory path.

If you do decide you want directories under your data directory, you can do that, but will have to make sure they exist or create them.